# ¿Cómo se puede llamar a funciones de una clase de otra clase de un mismo proyecto?

Tags: java

He creado un nuevo proyecto de java y en la carpeta `src` tengo dos archivos ".java".

[image: Carpeta src con los dos .java]

El archivo codigo_ident.java es el principal y quiero llamar a a la clase que tengo creada en el archivo CRC8.java.

¿Cómo  puedo hacer referencia de una clase para utilizar las funciones que tiene este?

Comment: Pues o creas una instancia de una clase en la otra o haces los métodos estáticos para llamarlos con sólo el nombre de la clase, eso es lo que estás preguntando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes crear un objeto de `CRC8.java` en la clase `codigo_ident.java` asi:

`CRC8 miObjeto = new CRC8();`

Ahora para llamar sus funciones, propiedades, métodos, etc, debes usar ese objeto así:

`miObjeto.getMetodo();`

es decir, miObjeto llamará los métodos que programaste en `CRC8.java`.

Según veo en la imagen que nos compartes, estas usando VSCode; a menos que tengas un plugin que haga los imports automáticamente, debes importar la clase en la parte superior de la clase `codigo_ident.java` así:

`import paquete.CRC8;`

donde "paquete" es el nombre del paquete donde estas conteniendo las clases que nos muestras en la imagen.

En resumen, tu archivo `codigo_ident.java` debe tener una apariencia mas o menos a lo que sigue:

```
import paquete.CRC8;
//otros imports...

public class codigo_ident {

 public void miEjemplo(){
   CRC8 miObjeto = new CRC8();
   miObjeto.getMetodo();
   //...
 }
 //...
}
```

Comment: Otra opción es hacer herencia de CRC8.java a codigo_ident.java, así: public class codigo_ident extends CRC8 { ...

Comment: Una observación, para los nombres de las clases java recomienda usar Upper Camel case, en el caso de codigo_ident, podrias usar el nombre CodigoIdent

Comment: Muchas gracias @fer.trecool !